# How to build a setup.py with directories of files

Tags: python, python-3.x

My setup.py looks like this

```
setup = (
    name='foo',
    packages=['bin'],
    package_data={'':['data/*.dat','data/usr/*/*.dat']},
)
```

And my directory looks like,

```
main_directory\
     main.py
     bin\
       modules.py
       functions.py
     data\
       main_data.dat
         otherdata\
            otherdata.dat
```

`main.py` is the controller of the the functions and modules, are there any problems with my package structures? How can I build a right `setup.py` and after install I can open it from terminal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you've misunderstood the `setup.py` creation. In the `distutils` (and `setuptools`) package there's a function called `setup()`. I think you want tu use it, but you're creating a tuple and assigning it to a variable called `setup`. Also, `name` should be a string.

It should be like this:

```
from distutils.core import setup

setup(
    name='foo',
    packages=['bin'],
    package_data={'':['data/*.dat','data/usr/*/*.dat']},
)
```

You can install the above (saved as `setup.py`) using:

```
python setup.py install
```

After this is done, you can use your package in the Python shell or other Python files like this:

```
import foo
from foo.bin.modules import whatever
whatever()
# assuming you have a function called whatever in bin/modules.py
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for reminding me, I did it in my file, but after I use (pip3 setup.py install) I cannot use it like I use python3 main.py in the directory.

Comment: @ sorry i hit enter accidentally just now

Comment: Do not use `pip`, just `python setup.py install`

Comment: An of course, you have to import it anyway! (`import foo` or whatever the name is)

Comment: so i should import my main.py in the setup.py?

Comment: No I meant you have to import the installed module to use it

Comment: I edited my answer to make it more clear, have a look!

Comment: Thanks! That is quite understandable! How can I make that program executable in the terminal after install, I can see the 'foo' installed in pip3 list

Comment: What do you mean with *make that program executable*? If you see it in the pip list, it was installed correctly and you can use it as I wrote in my answer. Or did I misunderstand your comment?

Comment: @linsug Sorry for confusing! Although i can found that in pip list, but I cannot open it on terminal like : foo or python3 foo. I can run the program when I use _python3 main.py... But the problem is I cannot write a setup.py to build a distribution. I cannot run the program after it get installed. Wondering if I use the right path to set the setup.py

Comment: Can you do it like this with any other module? If you yust want to run the program on another PC and not use it as module for further programming, you schould probably create an executable with cx_freeze or PyInstaller!